# File upload using JInput! possible?

Tags: php, jinput

i use a html form on one of my articles, i am successful in getting the values from the form using JInput!

```
$input = JFactory::getApplication()->input;
```

But now i need  to add a **file upload** input to the form :

```
<input type="file" name="upload">
```

How to upload and save files on the server using JInput!?

> **File upload with restrictions, allowing only specific file extentions.**

Comment: Have you tried any code yet to get the upload working? is `File upload with restrictions, allowing only specific file extentions.` an error you're getting with your current code? If so, please show you current code

Comment: i tried using the global PHP $_FILES array method, but it doesn't work while using JInput!

Comment: Have a look here. This page uses `JRequest` so simply replace with your `JInput` code: http://docs.joomla.org/How_to_use_the_filesystem_package

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In addition to @Bakual's answer, let's assume you a simple form like so:

```
<form name="upload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="file_upload">
</form>
```

To upload the file once the submit button has been pressed, you can use this:

```
$input = JFactory::getApplication()->input;
$file  = $input->files->get('file_upload'); 

// Cleans the name of teh file by removing weird characters
$filename = JFile::makeSafe($file['name']); 

$src  = $file['tmp_name'];
$dest = JPATH_BASE . '/modules/mod_mymodule/' . $filename;

if (JFile::upload($src, $dest)) 
{
      // The file has successfully been uploaded :)
} 
else 
{
      // Oh crap, something happened. Run!
}
```

You will obviously need to change the path (`$dest`) to whatever suits your needs.

There is a load of validations you should perform when handling uploads, a lot of which can be found on the link you have been provided with already:

http://docs.joomla.org/How_to_use_the_filesystem_package

Comment: is this the path where the file will be uploaded "/modules/mod_mymodule/" ?

Comment: @Saibbyweb - yes

Comment: i am using this [$dest = JPATH_BASE . "/screen" . $filename;] and file is getting uploaded in the root directory with a prefix "screen" ?

Comment: I believe you should add a forward slash on to the end to it's `"/screen/"`. But yes, if this is the path you're defining then this is where the file will be uploaded

Comment: Maybe you could add code on how to get error message if the upload failed?

Answer (score 7):

There are two tricky things people usually fall over when it comes to file uploads using JInput:

- Your form tag needs to contain `enctype="multipart/form-data"`
- The file array is retrieved with `$input->files->get('upload');`

Comment: $input->files->get('upload'); will retrieve the file, how to save it to any specific directory? What would be the code for that?

Comment: `JFile::Upload`, see for example http://docs.joomla.org/How_to_use_the_filesystem_package#Upload_a_file or http://api.joomla.org/cms-3/classes/JFile.html#method_upload