# Upload single or multiple files replacing deprecated JRequest::getVar('file', '', 'files', 'array');

Tags: joomla-3.x, joomla-api, jinput

I am trying to upload a single or array of files and am not sure how to use the jinput with the array and filter. Tried multiple suggestions from here and documentation and cannot make it work for me.

```
// Get some data from the request
$file       = JRequest::getVar('file', '', 'files', 'array');
$file_id    = $this->input->get('file_id');
$folder     = $this->input->getString('folder');
$filter     = new JFilterInput();
$folder     = $filter->clean($folder, 'path');
```

Appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: You've seen this one? https://joomla.stackexchange.com/q/2217/12352

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
$this->input->files->get('file', [], 'array');
```

Note that returned data is formatted differently to allow iterating over files:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(5) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(16) "joomla_black.png"
    ["type"]=>
    string(9) "image/png"
    ["tmp_name"]=>
    string(23) "C:\wamp\tmp\php5788.tmp"
    ["error"]=>
    int(0)
    ["size"]=>
    int(4979)
  }
  [1]=>
  array(5) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(14) "powered_by.png"
    ["type"]=>
    string(9) "image/png"
    ["tmp_name"]=>
    string(23) "C:\wamp\tmp\php5798.tmp"
    ["error"]=>
    int(0)
    ["size"]=>
    int(3197)
  }
}
```

As opposed to having an array with properties as keys when using `JRequest`:

```
array(5) {
  ["name"]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(16) "joomla_black.png"
    [1]=>
    string(14) "powered_by.png"
  }
  ["type"]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(9) "image/png"
    [1]=>
    string(9) "image/png"
  }
  ["tmp_name"]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(23) "C:\wamp\tmp\php5788.tmp"
    [1]=>
    string(23) "C:\wamp\tmp\php5798.tmp"
  }
  ["error"]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    int(0)
    [1]=>
    int(0)
  }
  ["size"]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    int(4979)
    [1]=>
    int(3197)
  }
}
```